# how to get location updates for every n secs in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, cocos2d-iphone

I want to get the location updates for every 30 secs.In foreground and when the app is in background.Also how could I know that my location is updating or not if I use simulator.please provide some help.

Comment: You can fake a location for the simulator. xCode has some options for that though I never used them myself.

Answer (score 2):

You don't, you get location update when the device moves. Location update are not really meant to be polled, but rather you are notified when there is a new location available.

Just create a instance of [`CLLocationManager`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html) and start call the `startUpdatingLocation` method. Then the delegate of the [`CLLocationManager`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html) will start receiving location updates. Just be aware that if you keep this running for a long time it will drain the devices battery faster.